# Jest doesn't get css classes

Tags: reactjs, sass, ts-jest

I'm trying to start implementing basic tests in a React + Ts + Vite application, but when I try to check if the css classes have been defined correctly I get undefined.
This is the component:

```
import styles from './HighlightedBox.module.scss'

type HighlightedBoxProps = {
    state: String
}

export const HighlightedBox = ({state}: HighlightedBoxProps) => {

    function capitalize(str: String){
       return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();

    }

    return <div className={styles.container + " " + 
    (state.toLowerCase() === "rechazado" ? styles.failed : styles.passed)}>
        <span className={styles.highlightText}>{capitalize(state)}</span>
    </div>

}
```

This is the styles file:

```
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .25em .5em;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.highlightText{
    line-height: 1;
}
.passed{
    background-color: var(--green-color-2);
    color: var(--green-color-8);
}
.failed{
    background-color: var(--red-color-1);
    color: var(--red-color-7);
}
```

These are the tests:

```
import { render, screen, prettyDOM } from '@testing-library/react';
import { HighlightedBox } from './HighlightedBox';
import { EstadoDictamen } from '../../enums/EstadoDictamen';

describe('HighlightedBox', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    const component = render(<HighlightedBox state={'rechazado'} />);
  })

  it('should render a box with the correct class based on the state', () => {
    const boxElement = screen.getByRole('div');
    expect(boxElement).toHaveClass('failed');
  });

  it('should capitalize the state text', () => {
    render(<HighlightedBox state={EstadoDictamen.Aprobado} />);
    const textElement = screen.getByText('Aprobado');
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

When I run the tests, in the first one I get:

```
 <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="undefined undefined"
        >
          <span>
            Rechazado
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Also I get another error for not being able to find the 'div':

```
● HighlightedBox › should render a box with the correct class based on the state

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "div"

    There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, 
then set the `hidden` option to `true`. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole

      10 |
      11 |   it('should render a box with the correct class based on the state', () => {
    > 12 |     const boxElement = screen.getByRole('div');
         |                               ^
      13 |     expect(boxElement).toHaveClass('failed');
      14 |   });
      15 |
```

I solved using the solution provided in comments, and additionally, using the comment of nicolashemonic in https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy/issues/8

Comment: Can you also share your styles file?

Comment: `getByRole('div')` will fail because `div` is not a role. Rather use `find('div')`.

Comment: With the other solution, I got able to find the element, but I'm still facing the problem of the class="" or class="undefined undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using CSS modules, the class name that is assigned to the element will anyway be uniquely generated and hence will not be deterministic.

A better practice is to add `data-testid` attributes to the elements you want to select in tests.

```html
<div data-testid="my-container"></div>
```

and then query the `div` using `getByTestId()`.

```js
screen.getByTestId('my-container')
```

Ref: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/

Comment: That actually worked! Tysm!
But I am still getting error because the class 'failed' can't be found in "undefined undefined":
```
expect(element).toHaveClass("failed")

    Expected the element to have class:
      failed
    Received:
      undefined undefined
11 |   it('should render a box with the correct class based on the state', () => {
12 |     const boxElement = screen.getByTestId('my-container')
> 13 |     expect(boxElement).toHaveClass('failed');
    |                        ^
14 |   });
15 |
16 |   it('should capitalize the state text', () => {
```

Comment: @NicoGodoy It fails because `"failed"` is not same as `styles.failed`. You could rather mock imported `styles` module to export a `failed` string variable and then validate using `expect(element).toHaveClass(styles.failed)`.

Comment: I tried importing styles in the test and making a reference to it, but I still get undefined undefined. Also, I just tried using classNames and now the component class is just "" lol

Answer (score 0):

You can run Jest tests with CSS-modules.

I have made an example in a CRA-app and can check for a css class from a module without using data-testid.

In the example below I use 'classes' instead of 'styles', but it shows a simple example of how you can test in Jest:

```
// Date.tsx
import classes from './Date.module.css';
interface ComponentProps {
  date: string;
}
export const Date = ({ date }: ComponentProps) => (
  <h3 className={classes.date}>{date}</h3>
);
```

```
/* Date.module.css */
.date {
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```
// Date.test.tsx
import { Date } from './Date';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import classes from './Date.module.css';
describe('Date', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const className = classes.date;
    console.log('classname is ', className);
    const date = '2021-10-01';
    render(<Date date={date} />);
    const element = screen.getByText('2021-10-01');
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
    screen.debug();
    expect(element).toHaveClass(className);
  });
});
```

Inspecting the console output you can see that jest uses the non-hashed classNames

```
Console output:
  ./Date.test.tsx
  console.log
    classname is  date

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Date.test.tsx:7:13)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <h3
          class="date"
        >
          2021-10-01
        </h3>
      </div>
    </body>

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:87:13)
```

It wouldn't make sense to test if the className has been hashed. It seems as long as you use jest as configured in the react-scripts, package it is possible to check if the css classes are applied to the right elements.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).